# How to sort on page load and also display an image based on sort in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have the following code (asp.net and code-behind) that achieves the sort:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PullData("", "");
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "";
    }
}
public void PullData(string sortExp, string sortDir)
{
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    string connString = @"user id = dsfsdfds;" + "password= sadasdada; server=  mg; database= ob;" /*+ "Trusted_Connection=yes;"*/  + "connection timeout=30";
    string query = @"SELECT  'http://mg/appnet/workview/objectPop.aspx?objectid=' + CAST(CT.OBJECTID AS VARCHAR) + '&classid=1224' 'Task Detail'
            ,UG.USERGROUPNAME 'Services'
            ,CT.ATTR2812 'Status'
            ,CT.ATTR2752 'Due Date'
            ,CT.ATTR2739 'Task Name'

        FROM dbo.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT
        WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            DataView myDataView = new DataView();
            myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            if (sortExp != string.Empty)
            {
                myDataView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir);
            }

            yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

protected void yourTasksGV_Sorting(object server, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    PullData(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
}
public string sortOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "Desc")
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Asc";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "Desc";
        }

        return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
    }
}
```

My `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E2E2E2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Details" SortExpression="Task Detail" ItemStyle-Width="35%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Services" HeaderText="Services" SortExpression="Services" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

For the first column I am taking the `Task Name` and showing as the display text for the link in `Task Detail` column from the SQL query (DataTextField is Task Name instead of Task Details).

How can I modify my code to do the following:

1. When I click on the `Task Details` tab it should sort by the `Task Name` that is shown as the display for the link which is the `Task Detail`?
2. Display an image next to the header text which I am sorting the table by? (up.png and down.png)?
3. On page load, sort by #1 ASC and display the image respectively?

My `GridView` that is being shown to the user (Note how the first column the link is used inside the `href` and the display text is the `Task Name`):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an useful solution here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/08/28/gridview-with-sort-arrows-and-showing-header-when-empty.aspx

and you can do this
to display image use this code:

```
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //Call the GetSortColumnIndex helper method to determine
        //the index of the column being sorted.

        int sortColumnIndex = GetSortColumnIndex();

        if (sortColumnIndex != -1)
        {
            // Call the AddSortImage helper method to add
            // a sort direction image to the appropriate
            // column header. 
            AddSortImage(sortColumnIndex, e.Row);
        }
    }
}

int GetSortColumnIndex()
{
    // Iterate through the Columns collection to determine the index
    // of the column being sorted.
    foreach (DataControlField field in gv.Columns)
    {
        if (field.SortExpression == gv.SortExpression)
        {
            return gv.Columns.IndexOf(field);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

    void AddSortImage(GridViewRow headerRow) 
{ 
     int iCol = GetSortColumnIndex();
     if (-1 == iCol) 
           return; 

     // Create the sorting image based on the sort direction.

     Image sortImage = new Image();
     if (SortDirection.Ascending == this.GridView1.SortDirection) 

{             sortImage.ImageUrl = @"~\Images\BlackDownArrow.gif"; 
               sortImage.AlternateText = "Ascending Order"; 
}     else  
{
             sortImage.ImageUrl = @"~\Images\BlackUpArrow.gif";
             sortImage.AlternateText = "Descending Order";
}
      // Add the image to the appropriate header cell. 
        headerRow.Cells[iCol].Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;"));
        headerRow.Cells[iCol].Controls.Add(sortImage); 
}
```

and to sort, enable gridview "allowsorting property" and add `Sort Expression" to the columns properties.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Where is the image being displayed?